# android layout-land and screen-rotation handling

Tags: android, layout, screen, rotation

I have layouts for portrait mode (in folder layout) and for landscape one (in the folder layout-land). This screen is located under one of the tabs, so I had to handle screen rotating (after screen has been rotated, no default screen restart occurs).

I would like to update view from 'layout-land' when screen rotates to landscape mode and from 'layout' when screen rotates to portrait one.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use onConfigchange method in that setContentView(R.layout.name) this way will work.

Comment: The main thing I don't like in this is that I use custom view inside layout and I need to save all its variables ... Also all variables concerned to layout :(

Comment: What if you need to use an `xml` from the `layout-land` folder? Any `xml` in my `layout` folder gets forced into portrait view, yet I really want to manually set the landscape `xml` when configuration changes. Thanks if you know.